# Onpress wait for a function to be finished, then continue in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have problems with the synchronisation of my code, my program is reacting on the second button press, as it should have on the first button press.
(explained detailed on the bottom).

I have the following Firebase API function:

```
export const noOpponent = (Key, setOpponent) => {
  console.log("key: " + Key)
  duettsRef
    .where("key", "==", Key)
    .where("player1", "!=", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .where("player2", "==", "")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
     setOpponent(!querySnapshot.empty)
     console.log("QuerysnapshotResult: " + !querySnapshot.empty)
      })
};
```

Now I got another .js document which includes the following code (shortened):

```
 const DuellScreen = () => {
     const [opponent, setOpponent] = useState(null);
     return (
...
       <BlockButton
                    text="Apply"
                    onPress={() => {
                      noOpponent(code, setOpponent);
                      console.log("OPPONENT:" + opponent),
                      opponent ? (
                         opponent == true?(
                             setKeyToDuett(code),
                              Platform.OS === "android"?(
                                ToastAndroid.show("Game joined!", ToastAndroid.SHORT)):
                                (Alert.alert("Game joined!"))
                          ):(
                            Platform.OS === "android"?(
                              ToastAndroid.show("Game does not exist or someone else has already joined!", ToastAndroid.SHORT)):
                              (Alert.alert("Game does not exist or someone else has already joined"))
                          )
                          ):(
                        console.log("opponent is probably null")
                      )}
                  }  
                    />
...
)
```

Now with the first press on my button, i get the following lines printed:

```
OPPONENT:null
opponent is probably null
QuerysnapshotResult: true
```

With the second button press, i get:

```
OPPONENT:true
QuerysnapshotResult: true
```

The result from the second button press, is the result i expected from the first button press already...
I think, after calling `noOpponent(code, setOpponent);` its just jumping instantly in the next line `(opponent ? (...`, where opponent is still null, because its not waiting for the result/change of my `opponent` from the `noOpponent function`. On the second button press its then set true, because of the first button press.
And its printing out `console.log("OPPONENT:" + opponent)` before `console.log("QuerysnapshotResult: " + !querySnapshot.empty)`

How can I synchronise this correctly, that my program is waiting for the result of the `noOpponent` function which sets the `opponent` correctly and then jumps in this line  `opponent ?` (

Comment: use promise to achieve this.

Comment: @DipanSharma I tried it already, but I still get OPPONENT:... printed out before QuerysnapshotResult: ... So its still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need using async method or Promise, try it

```
export const noOpponent = (Key, setOpponent) => {
console.log("key: " + Key)
duettsRef
    .where("key", "==", Key)
    .where("player1", "!=", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .where("player2", "==", "")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        setOpponent(!querySnapshot.empty)
        console.log("QuerysnapshotResult: " + !querySnapshot.empty)
    })
```

};

Then for onPress Button.

```
onPress={async () => {
    await noOpponent(code, setOpponent);
    console.log("OPPONENT:" + opponent),
    opponent ? (
        opponent == true ? (
              setKeyToDuett(code),
              Platform.OS === "android"?(
              ToastAndroid.show("Game joined!", ToastAndroid.SHORT)):
              (Alert.alert("Game joined!"))
        ):(
              Platform.OS === "android"?(
                  ToastAndroid.show("Game does not exist or someone else has already joined!", ToastAndroid.SHORT)):
                  (Alert.alert("Game does not exist or someone else has already joined"))
          )
      ):(
          console.log("opponent is probably null")
    )}
}
```

Comment: Do i have to change up something on the ` const noOpponent` too? When I try it like you stated, on the first button press the console logs:                                                                      
OPPONENT:null, 
opponent is probably null, 
QuerysnapshotResult: false So its still not working, and printing in the wrong order

Comment: @Grrrrrag I do believe you have to redo the `const noOpponent`, as I can see that you've established `.where("player2", "==", "")` which I believe should always give "" as the opponent? The docs seem to suggest using "exists" over "empty", it's possible that snapshot's docs need to be read/viewed before it's size/emptiness is established. Also, may I ask where "opponent" is being set?

Comment: Yeah @fabc, maybe your problem is your query too.

Comment: @Grrrrrag Could you please tell us if you were able to solve the issue? If not we will look further.